# FancyBox2 causes Firefox 13 to shift a div when scroll bar comes up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, fancybox-2

Heeey so I have a problem (of course). I have a basic php site (php part not important) that uses Jquery FancyBox2. I'm just about to demo the alpha version of site to the contractor, but I have one snag. When a FancyBox2 Jquery is executed, in Firefox 13 (and only Firefox, not the most recent versions of IE, Opera, or Chrome) the box pops up fine, but the corresponding entire parent document y-scroll bar pops up, and shifts the whole site off by like left:-10 px, and when you close the FancyBox2 instance it shifts back to normal. No other browser seems to shift the sites content when the blank y-scroll bar comes up with a FancyBox2 instance. I'd like to not have this happen? Here's some basic code:

CSS: yes, it's a bit overloaded, ignore the faults and focus on the issue at hand, alpha stage of both backend and design.

```
body
{
font-family:            'Goudy Bookletter 1911', serif;
overflow-x:             hidden;
text-align:             center;
horizontal-align:       baseline;
color:                  #4D60A4;
}
#site_container
{
-moz-user-select:       -moz-none;          /* disable div selection */
-khtml-user-select:     none;
-webkit-user-select:    none;
-o-user-select:         none:
user-select:            none;
zoom:                   1;                  /* for ie6 */
background-image:       url('http://192.168.254.134:8080/images/main_back6.jpg');
background-repeat:      no-repeat;
background-size:        cover;
width:                  980px;
min-height:             780px;
text-align:             left;
height:                 100%;
left:                   50%;
padding:                0px;
border:                 0px solid #0000FF;
overflow:               hidden;
margin:                 0px auto;
margin-top:             -50px;
}
```

php: example of how FancyBox2 is called in this site.

```
echo "<a class='fancybox' href='" . $row['image1'] . "'>";
echo "<img src='" . $row['image1'] . "' width=200 height=200 /></a>";
```

js: how i call FancyBox2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    ...
});
```

Comment: i thought about trying to create an onclick function that replaces the fancybox_get_viewport that gets called a few milliseconds after an onclick instance, but that seems like too much work? suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OOOkay, got it. I'm more of a backend guy, not a design guy. Just had to add this to the css:

```
body
{
...
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow: scroll;
...
}
```

and that fixed it. Wonder why only firefox needed that hierarchical fix? Is overflow: scroll css3? anyways, nevermind.

Comment: derp! it has to be "overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;" in that order for the site to still have no x-scroll bar but also fix the offset when the fancybox iframe temporarily creates a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Has no effect apart from break other unrelated things

Comment: any particular reason you down-voted a self-resolved question? the answer worked, and "no effect from break other unrelated things" is a totally useless comment outside of the context its meant for.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush. Apologies. I'll investigate a bit more and get back to you, it may be that I misunderstood your problem and it's different to mine. If it turns out it is different I'll remove the down vote. Otherwise I'll provide some extra details.

Comment: Ok, this fixed my issue in conjunction with another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056039/page-layout-breaks-when-fancybox-initiated-in-firefox-16-0-1.